# Refresh object in Session from Database Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate, as I know updates the Database once the attached Objects in the session's value changes. Is there a way to obtain a fresh copy from the database and reattach the fresh copy discarding the changed object?

Below is an object I obtained from Querying the Database using Hibernate.

```
Rtpmast rtpmast = (Rtpmast) iterator.next();
```

Once executed the below code

```
rtp.setRptval1(promotionMethod.getType());
```

Hibernate registers that the the object has changed. And when I commit a transaction later on or query the Database the Session is flushed?

What I want is to temporally update the `Rtpmast object` and discard the changed object later.

Comment: I found the lead - Hibernate evict() method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hibernate, as I know updates the Database once the attached Objects
>   in the session's value changes.

Actually,Hibernate updates the database only after invoking `session.save(...)`, `session.delete(...)` etc. methods. If you're in a transaction you'd also have to `commit` changes.

What you want is either use `evict()` and re-query the object, as you've mentioned, or detach the instance you're working on, which means you need to `close()` the `Session` (there are other, less trivial, ways to do so as mentioned [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=988857&view=next)).

Comment: Oh thanks... Do I need to close() the session to detach the object?

Comment: That's one of the typical ways.